# rpy2 accrual problem('InstalledSTPackage' object has no attribute 'n')

Tags: r, rpy2

Please help me with the error in the source code.

This is for Linux server, running python, R, rpy2.

Source Code

```
import os,re,sys
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
accrual = importr('accrual','tcltk2')
print accrual.n.inform(n=300, T=36, P=0.5, m=100, tm=10, Tp=36)[[1]]
```

Error Message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 4, in
>
> `print accrual.n.inform(n=300, T=36, P=0.5, m=100, tm=10, Tp=36)`[[1]]
>
> AttributeError: '`InstalledSTPackage`' object has no attribute '`n`'

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there is no object called `n` in R package `accrual`. Did you mean to write the following ?

```
print(accrual.accrual_n_inform(n=300, T=36, P=0.5, m=100, tm=10, Tp=36))
```

The documentation contains hints about what is happening: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html